# How to cite a tool without any publicly available paper/bibtex entry

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

Is there a commonly accepted bibtex format for citing software/tools that exist on github and have documentation, but dont have bibtex entries?

For instance, to cite a tool maintained on github

@online{tool,
title = {title goes here},
url = {https://github.com/toolname},
urldate = {2021-09-09}}

Is this entry valid for Springer lncs bibtex format?

Comment: what exactly do you mean by `but dont have bibtex entries` and note that `@online` will need a very specific bibtex style to be supported (generally it is used with `biblatex`), not sure if `biblatex` is supported by Soringer lncs. Otherwise use the `@misc` type

Comment: Well, there's the catch-all `@misc` entry type, which has no *required* fields. Most bibliography styles will recognize and process the fields `howpublished` and `note`, if present in `@misc`-type entries. You could use either field to provide URL strings. Some (but not all) bibliography styes will also recognize and process fields name `url` and `urldate`.

Comment: Alternatively you can also refer to the tool in a footnote (including the url and date) instead of including it in the bibliography.

Comment: thanks! I ll stick with @misc